# geospatial queries on subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with subdocuments that contain a location field (with 2dSpehre index). Like this:

```
var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    addresses: [
        {
            address: {
                street: String,
                city: String,
                zip: String,
                country: String
            },
            loc: { type: [Number], index: '2dSphere' }
        }
    ],
});
```

When I try to query for addresses via geospatial operators I get this error: `planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query`. The query looks like this:

```
var query = {
    'addresses.loc': {
        $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [16.3738189, 48.2081743] }
        }
    }
};
Player.find(query).exec();
```

I also checked via mongo that the index really exists:

```
> db.player.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "project.player"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "addresses.loc" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "addresses.loc_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "project.player",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right collection? Mongoose will pluralize your collection name by default (so `players` instead of `player`).

The script below is working for me. For some reason Mongoose wasn't creating the `2dsphere` index for me when it was specified in the schema so I moved that out.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    addresses: [
        {
            address: {
                street: String,
                city: String,
                zip: String,
                country: String
            },
            loc: { 'type': { type: String }, 'coordinates': { type: [Number] } }
        }
    ],
});

playerSchema.index({'addresses.loc': '2dsphere'});
var Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var query = Player.find({
    'addresses.loc': {
        $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [16.3738189, 48.2081743] }
        }
    }
}, function (err, players) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(players)
});
```

Comment: I noticed that I had a typo: it is `index: '2dsphere'` instead of `index: '2dSphere'`.